# Windows 2008 R2 domain account question

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a stand alone server on a workgroup that is not part of the primary company domain.

I want to add a domain account to the administrator group of this stand alone server.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Add the server to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

No. Add the server to the domain

Answer (score 1):

If you create a local account in that group, with the same username & password, the user in question probably won't realise that its not on the domain until they try and use domain resources from that machine.. its best to just have it on the domain.

Is there any reason for its "non-domain" stasis?